# Соединение проекта в Visual Studio с базой данных MS SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql

Есть некоторое имя сервера SQL Server, например DESKTOP-1TU. В своем проекте в VS в файле App.config прописываю следующее:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="LibraryContext" connectionString="data source=DESKTOP-1TU;initial catalog=LibraryDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Однако при запуске проекта выводится ошибка:

FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd89'.

Ожидалось успешное подключение к серверу и создание новой БД с именем LibraryDB. Что нужно изменить, чтобы произвести подключение к БД? Откуда взять System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.3.0?

Я что то не правильно указываю в connectionString? Как исправить данную ошибку? Вот остальной код на всякий случай:

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
}

public class LibraryContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public LibraryContext()
        : base("name=LibraryContext")
    {
    }   
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (LibraryContext context = new LibraryContext())
        {
            Book book = new Book();
            book.Title = "Война и мир";
            book.Author = "Лев Толстой";

            context.Books.Add(book);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А у вас `system.configuration.configurationamanger` Nuget пакет установлен?

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev как оказалось установлен он не был. Благодарю за решение проблемы. Однако теперь возникает другая ошибка: System.InvalidOperationException: "No connection string named 'LibraryContext' could be found in the application config file."
Но мой App.config содержит LibraryContext. Изначально создавая консольное приложение я не мог добавить ADO.NET EDM. Поэтому в решение добавил еще один проект Class Library, добавил ADO туда. Указал ссылки и использование namespace. Теперь у меня в решении два проекта. Конфиг как и вся логика с бд - в одном, метод мейн - в другом.

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev Основной проект с точкой входа в программу имеет в зависимостях ссылку на Class Library. Неймспейс тоже прописан. Может ли быть причиной ошибки то, что App.config в одном проекте, а точка входа в программу в другом? Или причина какая то другая?

Comment: На всякий случай, вы понимаете, что у Class Library не может быть своего app.config? То есть параметры для Class Library нужно вписывать в app.config приложения, к которому оно подключено.